# Vue element with multiple exact click handlers always executes click.exact method when clicked with system modifiers

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, event-handling, vue-component

As per https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#exact-Modifier, I'm trying to create an element that executes different methods, depending on which keys are also pressed at click-time.

```
<span @click.exact="method1"
      @click.shift.exact="method2"
      @click.alt.exact="method3"
>Click me with or without modifiers</span>
```

A click on the rendered text executes `method1`. This is correct, however the method also gets executed prior to `method2` on a SHIFT + Click, and prior to `method3` on an ALT + Click. The expected behavior is that `method1` to be only executed on a click, when no system modifier keys are pressed.

edit: I claimed that Version 2.5 of Vue was being used, but the "latest" linked version was 2.3, which does not have the "exact" feature.

The complete codepen for the example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bjKRzV

Comment: you used wrong vue version (if you open `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/latest/vue.js`, you will see the verion# is **2.3**, not 2.5), try [this codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NBzvJX?editors=1111) with external lib is `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js`

Comment: who would have thought that https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/latest/vue.js is not the latest vue version... that fixed it

Comment: Damn. It's not even close.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you might be using the wrong Vue version. If you're stuck with an older version you will likely need to do something like `@click="handleClick"` then in `handleClick` check the `event` for `shiftKey` or `altKey` or whatever.

So something like:

```
handleClick (event) {
  if (event.shiftKey) {
    this.method2()
  } else if (event.altKey) {
    this.method3()
  } else {
    this.method1()
  }
}
```